# How to pass system properties to gradle tests with kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to pass system properties to my gradle tests. With standard gradle, I would use

```
test {
    //... Other configurations ...
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

With kotlin DSL, this won't run:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    options {
        systemProperties(System.getProperties())
    }
}
```

The problem is that properties is `HashTable` and expected type is `Map<String, String>`.

Right now, I use following workaround:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    val props = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    System.getProperties().forEach {
        val key = it.key
        val value = it.value

        if (key is String && value is String) {
            props[key] = value
        }
    }
    options {
        systemProperties(props)
    }
}
```

Any clue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
systemProperties = System.getProperties().map { e -> Pair(e.key as String, e.value) }.toMap()
```

To pass a single system property:

```
systemProperty("property.name", System.getProperty("property.name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting the `Properties` object to a `Map<String, *>` works as well.

```kotlin
systemProperties(System.getProperties() as Map<String, *>)
```